# Is there any relation between fatigue and irritability?

Tags: fatigue, irritability

Is there any relation between **fatigue** and irritability ?

Although I am interested by fatigue in the sense of lack of sleep, I am mostly interested by fatigue in the sense of the feeling of depletion after a prolonged effort (basically, after having worked whole day, or a few days, without enough rest (but without necessarily lack of sleep)).

I fail to find any research on this topic, outside the ego-depletion literature. Most of the results that come up with a research on Google Scholar concern the "bowel syndrome".

The only one I found is Baumeister et al. 2018 ("[Self-control “in the wild”: Experience sampling study of trait and state self-regulation](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/15298868.2018.1478324?journalCode=psai20)").

**Reference**

Baumeister, R. F., Wright, B. R., & Carreon, D. (2018). Self-control “in the wild”: Experience sampling study of trait and state self-regulation. *Self and Identity*, 18(5), 494-528.

Comment: Have you tried searching "fatigue and irritability" in [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/). There are lots that come up. For example, https://doi.org/10.1080/15402002.2019.1698426

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thank you for your guidance. I edited my post. I read the abstract of the paper you shared (don't have access to the whole paper). Seems there is no relationship found between fatigue (in the sense lack of sleep) and irritability, am I correct? I didn't understand the sentences "Greater self-reported total sleep time predicted lower recovery stress, fatigue, and irritability. Greater subjective sleep efficiency predicted lower recovery stress and fatigue, but not irritability." What is "lower recovery ... "?